# Substitute a character literally in a regular expression in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have a regular expression similar to this :-

```
abc{some dynamic character}abc
```

I want to substitute a character within braces at run-time. This dynamic character may be a special character (meta-characters, escape characters etc.).

How can I ensure that this dynamically formed regular expression is same as the one written by putting this character statically. (like *"abc\\nabc"*)

**Example :-**
Dynamic Character : `'\n'`
Static Regular Expression : `"abc\\nabc"`
Dynamic regex should be equal to static regex after replacing the character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Pattern class to escape your dynamic character:

```
"abc"  + Pattern.quote(dynamicCharacter) "abc"
```

Comment: Note that `Pattern.quote` takes a `String` so if `dynamicCharacter` is actually a `char` (as it appears from the question) then you need `Pattern.quote(Character.toString(dynamicCharacter))`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply..Suppose, I have a very complex regular expressions and 2-3 variables to substitute in between, then should we use `MessageFormat` to substitute the variables in the regex.